# Recommendation for 3rd party editing/syntax highlighting control - WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, components

I'm looking for a quality WinForms component that supports syntax highlighting, code folding and the like. The key criteria are:

1. Stability
2. Value (price)
3. Ability to easily customize syntax to highlight
4. Light weight

Answer (score 8):

[ICSharpCode.TextEditor](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) is free and pretty stable.
As for commercial solution Actipro's [SyntaxEditor](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/Products/DotNet/SyntaxEditor/Default.aspx) might be a best choice

Comment: SnippetCompiler http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/ uses ActiPro for its editor, too.

Comment: BTW, in case anyone wonders, ActiPro doesn't support Client Profile.

Answer (score 5):

Enhancing ICSharpCode.TextEditor was trivial compared with Scintilla.Net. Another huge benefit of ICSharpCode.TextEditor is that allows you to customize/build your own Syntax Highlighting, eg: https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/Syntax-highlighting.

**BUT ICSharpCode.TextEditor is not stable**, its riddled with AccessViolations: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=icsharpcode.texteditor+accessviolationexception

You can see these AccessViolations first hand by downloading:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor

This build on GitHub behaves better in winforms, but in VSTO it still screams AccessViolations:
https://github.com/KindDragon/ICSharpCode.TextEditor

Same as [DigitalRune's version of the ICsharp.TextEditor](http://www.digitalrune.com/Downloads/DigitalRuneTextEditorControl.aspx).

I'd recommend the latest WPF implementation: [ICSharp.AvalonEdit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor).

If you need to host this WPF control in Winforms:

```
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.TextEditor te = new ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.TextEditor();
ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
host.Size = new Size(200, 100);
host.Location = new Point(100, 100);
host.Child = te;
this.Controls.Add(host);
}
```

---

Some commercial ones I came across (note I'm not affiliated with these companies):
http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/controls/windowsforms/syntaxeditor
http://www.qwhale.net/products/editor.htm

Answer (score 3):

Try out [ScintillaNET](http://www.codeplex.com/ScintillaNET) it's a .NET WinForms wrapper around the excellent [Scintilla](http://scintilla.org/) control. Scintilla itself is a free source code editor component that is very customisable and has all the features you asked for. See [here](http://scintilla.sourceforge.net/SciTEImage.html) for a screenshot.

Comment: The only problem with ScintillaNET is that you'll have more unmanaged dependencies to pull Scintilla in.

Comment: A little Update to ScintillaNET - Until now (9/2011) the bindings are incomplete and have some hard to find bugs in it. For example if you select a full line, the first char is hightlighted but not in the selection - Right now I am searching for a replacement of ScintillaNet...