# A XML-enabled C# TextBox?

Tags: c#, xml, textbox

Visual Studio displays XML on a special text box which

- Properly indents the XML hierarchy;
- Angle brackets are blue;
- Elements are brown;
- Attributes are red;
- Strings are blue
- Comments are green.

Where can I get a special "TextBox" like this, in C#, which is specialized to display XML to use in my code?

Note I don't need a whole library with a lot of functionalities - all I need is a TextBox that display XML in different colors and indents.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a simple textbox as it is rather complex to handle syntax highlighting. A good open-source solution for this that I have used in past is [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Features.aspx) from ICSharpCode. Part of the full IDE is a textbox-like control that you can use in your own application without the full-blown IDE.

Another option if you just want to *display* the XML, without editing, is to display the XML using the web browser, embedded as a user control. Not very light-weight, but definitely possible.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the name of the control? I downloaded and installed but couldn't find a control that does XML formatting.

Comment: Not sure which control, but the library is extensible so I think you need to attach a xshd file to get the highlight, see this link: http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/Syntax%20highlighting.ashx?HL=xml

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these links:

[Syncfusion](http://help.syncfusion.com/ug_74/edit/SyntaxHighlightingAndCodeEditing.html) --this is not free. It provides support for many languages (including XML). The URL explains how to achieve that.

There is [another post at stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41796/recommendation-for-3rd-party-editing-syntax-highlighting-control-winforms) discussing the same thing.